# Copying subfolders with their own files to another folder with WebClient in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, webclient

I'm copying an array of subfolders and array of files of the subfolders, the process is successful, but the files that are copied has no size. the `60 MB` file became `0 bytes` after being copied to another directory, what could be wrong?

this Is my code:

```
Dim WithEvents WebCopy As New WebClient

Dim foldersToCopy As New ArrayList()
Dim filesOfSub As New ArrayList()

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    foldersToCopy.Clear()
    filesOfSub.Clear()
    Dim src As String = Form2.TextBox1.Text
    Dim dest As String = Form2.TextBox2.Text

    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(src)
    Dim dii As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(dest)

' this is where I get the subfolders and its files.

    For Each sd In di.GetDirectories
        For Each fi In sd.GetFiles
            If Not Directory.Exists(dest & "\" & sd.Name) And Not File.Exists(dest & "\" & fi.Name) Then
                foldersToCopy.Add(sd.Name)
                filesOfSub.Add(fi.Name)
            End If
        Next
    Next

' this is where I create the subfolders
    For i = 0 To foldersToCopy.Count - 1
        If Not Directory.Exists(dest & "\" & dii.Name) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dest & "\" & foldersToCopy(i))
        End If
    Next

' this is where I copy the files of subfolders
    For i = 0 To filesOfSub.Count - 1
        Dim WebCopy As WebClient = New WebClient

        WebCopy.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(src & "\" & filesOfSub(i)), dest & "\" & foldersToCopy(i) & "\" & filesOfSub(i))

    Next 
End Sub
```

Btw, I'm using `WebClient` for its smooth progress bar and convinient use of handlers.

Comment: Can you put a debug.print statement above the WebCopy.DownloadFileAsync line to see what all the parameters of that call are and check the results?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to do that, I googled it and  I tried to put `Debug.Print("")` under the `Dim WebCopy As WebClient = New WebClient`  and imported `System.Diagnostics` . but nothing happens?

Comment: are those the things with `vshost.exe` and `The thread '<No Name>'` ?

Comment: Is this different from your earlier question [Copy Folders using Webclient in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144679/copy-folders-using-webclient-in-vb-net)?

Comment: uhm just a little bit, because I in that post I'm using a `FileSystem.CopyDirectory` to copy subfolders with its files that makes my application hang. but with this one I separated the process and the results are different. so, I think yes?hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank GOD I have found out the answer!

```
WebCopy.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(src & "\" & foldersToCopy(i) & "\" & filesOfSub(i)), dest & "\" & foldersToCopy(i) & "\" & filesOfSub(i))
```

this should be the correct form of my `DownloadFileAsync` copier.